# How to "merge/concat" an array and an object over a same property into a flat array(using Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv, javascript-objects

So I have an array with some items: `['apple','banana','strawberry','peach','orange']`. 
 I also have an object with same items (but not all of them) as properties:

```
{banana : 0,
strawberry : 2,
peach : 1}
```

I want to make a flat array with the items and theis values like the following:

```
['apple',  'not found'
'banana',     '0'
'strawberry,  '2'
'peach',      '1'
'orange',  'not found']
```

And at the end i want to write tha data into a csv file. I use the fast-csv module for that.

I tried doing with a for loop. Is there a faster more efficient way?

Edit: changed 2D array to flat array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with the desired output.

```js
let array = ['apple','banana','strawberry','peach','orange'],
    obj = {banana : 0,strawberry : 2,peach : 1},
    result = array.map(s => [s, s in obj ? obj[s] : "Not found"]);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It's not exactly the needed result. It should be `result = [].concat(...array.map(s => [s, s in obj ? obj[s] : "Not found"]));` to produce the desired outcome of a flat array rather than a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I think OP doesn't know the meaning of a 2D array given his desired output in the question - meaning he's looking for a flat array.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and it worked exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = ['apple','banana','strawberry','peach','orange'];
var it = {banana : 0,strawberry : 2,peach : 1};

item.map((key)=>{ return[ key, !it.hasOwnProperty(key) ? 'not found': it[key]];  })
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation for your answer?

Comment: Yes @rassar, So the requirement was of 2d array, which I created, you could test this. and just checking if the property exists on object, if yes then use the `key` else `not found`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a flat array (not a 2D) as per your example output, you could combine the answer from @Ele and add a spread operator like so:

```js
let array = ['apple','banana','strawberry','peach','orange'],
    obj = {banana : 0,strawberry : 2,peach : 1},
    result = [].concat(...array.map(s => [s, s in obj ? obj[s] : "Not found"]));
    
console.log(result);
```